# Lorentz force law and Ampère's force law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

The Lorentz force law specifies the force of a magnetic field on a moving charged particle, and the Ampere force law specifies the force of a magnetic field on a current carrying wire. I am trying to understand the relationship between these laws. Suppose we have a horizontal current carrying wire and either a moving charged particle or a current carrying wire above it:

[image: Lorentz force vs Ampere force]

Currents are in orange, moving particles in black, and forces in blue.

Am I right in thinking that the force on the moving particle should be the same as the force on the wire, because the wire has moving charged particles? If so, I have run into a difficulty: according to the [wikipedia page on Apere's force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law), the force between two current elements is directed along the line between the two current elements, see [this equation](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/bfecb19d06ced7e3ca5de55a2efd99c1c6d04304). This implies that the force is zero if the wires are perpendicular. However, the Lorentz force of a particle moving toward the wire seems to be directed parallel to the wire and nonzero.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is appropriate to answer my own question, but I found the answer. The equation on Wikipedia only applies with two closed circuits. For the force of one closed circuit on a current element it is missing a term. This term vanishes when integrated over a closed circuit. The correct equation for a current  element can be found in [Comparison of the Ampère and Biot-Savart magnetostatic force laws in their line-current-element forms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243490933_Comparison_of_the_Ampere_and_Biot-Savart_magnetostatic_force_laws_in_their_line-current-element_forms), equation (1).

Comment: Hi Jules: If you need any information regarding Ampere force law,  Grassmann force law, biot savart law, Lorentz force law, etc and some similar stuff, feel free to mail me at christianoronaldo1700@gmail.com